# C Linked List Initialization

Tags: c, linked-list

I don't know how to formulate a question when I don't know what's the problem at all, since I'm still new at the linked list stuff in C, anyhow this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Element{
    int val;
    struct Element* suivant;
}Element;

Element* initialiserListe(Element* L){
    L = NULL;
    return L;
}

Element* nouveau;
Element* insererEnTete(Element* L){
    nouveau = (Element*)malloc(sizeof(Element));
    if(L == NULL) printf("initialisation : ");
    printf("donner une valeur : ");
    scanf("%d", &nouveau->val);
    nouveau->suivant = L;
    return nouveau;
}

int listeVide(Element* L){
    return L == NULL;
}

void affichageListe(Element* L){
    if(listeVide(L)) printf("liste vide");
    else{
        Element* temp = L;
        while(temp != NULL){
            printf("%d", temp->val);
            temp = temp->suivant;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    Element *L = NULL;
    initialiserListe(L);
    insererEnTete(L);
    affichageListe(L);
    return 0;
}
```

all I want to know is why does it print "liste vide" when it should print the vals from the list

Comment: [Use da debbugeur](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), mec

Comment: Probably because you're not assigning the list returned by  call to function `insererEnTete(L);` to the variable `L`.

Comment: Why does `int f(int x) {x = 5; return x;} int main() {int i = 0; f(i); printf("%d\n", i); return 0;}` not print 5?

Comment: It appears that `L` is set to NULL in main and is never changed. The advice to use a debugger to step through your code is good advice - try it out. Best of luck.

Comment: You people are mean. It prints liste vide in affichageListe function because both initialiser and inserer do not change `L` since it only passed as a parameter.

Comment: @immibis. Cuz it doesn't know the right answer?

Comment: @texasbruce. Lets keep characters out of this please.

Comment: @AntonH maybe i don't get it, the purpose is to make the new element point at the first element of the variable L, which is a list of elements

Comment: @ZakariaeBou-taleb Yes, but as pointed out by others, what happens in a function stays in the function. So by passing L as a parametre, and changing it in the function, any changes are only valid within the function. You would have to return the appropriate value from the function, and have it assigned to the appropriate variable.

Comment: That is to say if you wanna change L (which is `Element*`), you need to pass the pointer to it (which is `Element**`) and do `*L = NULL` in your code.

Comment: @texasbruce That's one way to do it, but you forgot to mention that function call would require `&L`.

Comment: @AntonH That is correct (and assumed he knows)

Comment: @texasbruce Given the issue is caused by not assigning a return value, I assume nothing :)

Comment: If you use function name  in english it would be better. In first look , it seems   you are returning pointer to structure but not assigning

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the return values of your functions calls to `L` in your main function:

```
...
int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    Element *L = NULL;
    L = initialiserListe(L);
    L = insererEnTete(L);
    L = affichageListe(L);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to initialize L by using "initialiserListe" function because you already initialize it in main function and your code will be edited to be like this :

```
int main()
{
  printf("Hello world!\n");
    Element *L = NULL;
    L = insererEnTete(L);
     affichageListe(L);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well that made me feel stupid actually, thanks a lot it worked great